# Image in RecyclerView blinks on update

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I understand this question has been asked. My image blinks on ANY firebase child updates or changes. My RecyclerView does not blink, only the image within the RecyclerView, and NOT all of the images blink, only some of them. I am using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. Below is my code if you have any tips or helpful thoughts please let me know!
Thanks in advance.

```
private fun loadFirebaseReviews() {
    val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
    val order = postReviews.orderByChild("timestamp")
    order.keepSynced(true)
    val option = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<HomePosts>()
        .setQuery(order, HomePosts::class.java)
        .setLifecycleOwner(this)
        .build()

    firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
        object : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<HomePosts, ViewHolder>(option) {

            override fun onCreateViewHolder(
                parent: ViewGroup,
                viewType: Int
            ): ViewHolder {

                val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.home_posts, parent, false)

                return ViewHolder(view)
            }

            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int, posts: HomePosts) {
                val placeid = getRef(position).key.toString()
                var key = ""

                mRecyclerView.itemAnimator = null

                postReviews.child(placeid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object :
                    ValueEventListener {
                    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                        Log.w("LoadMyReviews,", "Failed to load My Reviews.")
                    }

                    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                        key = snapshot.key.toString()
                        if (itemCount == 0) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
                        mRecyclerView.itemAnimator = null
                        holder.photoURL.animation = null
                        holder.author.text = posts.author
                        holder.date.text = posts.date
                        holder.itemCategory.text = posts.itemCategory
                        holder.itemModel.text = posts.itemModel
                        holder.itemName.text = posts.itemName
                        holder.itemRating.rating = posts.itemRating
                        holder.itemRetailer.text = posts.itemRetailer
                        holder.itemReview.text = posts.itemReview
                        holder.itemTitle.text = posts.itemTitle
                        Picasso.get().load(posts.photoURL).into(holder.photoURL)

                    }
                }) //postReviewsValueListener

            } //OnBindViewHolder
        } //FirebaseRecycler

    mRecyclerView.adapter = firebaseRecyclerAdapter
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
} //loadFirebaseReviews
```

Here is my ImageView

```
<ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/itemPhoto"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="300dp"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_view_space"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/item_image"
                        android:maxHeight="300dip"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title" />
```

Comment: Is it possible it's this line `Picasso.get().load(posts.photoURL).into(holder.photoURL)` ? It looks like if any changes happen Picasso will try to reload the image via a URL. Also, I don't think you should need to call `firebaseRecyclerAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()` directly after creating the adapter.

Comment: I will have to see if there's another way to load the image with Picasso. I never thought about that! But it does make since that it could flicker the image every time.

Comment: You're right about the firebaseRecyclerAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged(). Thanks for pointing that out to me.

Comment: @CoryRoy Picasso loading the image was the problem. Thanks for the help!